# Ruby, послать сигнал из дочернего в родительский

Tags: ruby, процесс, subprocess

Нужно послать сигнал о том, что процесс завершился, из дочернего в родительский.
Но никак не получается заставить ловушку работать.

```rb
ppid = Process.pid
pid = fork do
  trap("USR1") do
    $stdout.syswrite("Hello world!\n")
    Process.kill("USR2", ppid)
    exit
  end
end
Process.kill("USR1", pid)
trap("USR2") { puts "Bye" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вы же не
[ждёте](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Process.html#method-c-wait)
завершения дочернего процесса!  Так работает:

```ruby
pid = fork do
  trap("USR1") do
    puts "Hello world!"
    Process.kill("USR2", Process.ppid)

    exit
  end
end

trap("USR2") { puts "Bye" }

Process.kill("USR1", pid)

Process.wait(pid)
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, понял свою ошибку!